# next page wrapped in a suspense not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm having some issues on production with this code. It's working great locally, but when i try to upload it on Netlify i'm getting this error
⨯ useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/imoveis".
and this bellow is the page in question, any ideia?

```
"use client";

import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { imoveis } from "../data/imoveis";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

const ImoveisPage = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const tipo = searchParams.get("tipo");

  const filteredImoveis = tipo
    ? imoveis.filter((imovel) => imovel.tipo === tipo)
    : [];

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-400 text-black min-h-screen p-8">
      <h1 className="text-2xl">Resultados da Pesquisa</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Carregando...</div>}>
        {filteredImoveis.length > 0 ? (
          <ul>
            {filteredImoveis.map((imovel, index) => (
              <li
                key={index}
                className="bg-neutral-200 m-2 text-black p-2 w-96"
              >
                <div>
                  <Link href={imovel.path}>
                    <p>{imovel.title}</p>
                    <p>{imovel.price}</p>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        ) : (
          <p>Nenhum resultado encontrado.</p>
        )}
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImoveisPage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The useSearchParams has to be called only after the Suspense context, you need a wrapper component that handles the suspense part.

```
const ImoveisPageWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-400 text-black min-h-screen p-8">
      <h1 className="text-2xl">Resultados da Pesquisa</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Carregando...</div>}>
        <ImoveisPage />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};

const ImoveisPage = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const tipo = searchParams.get("tipo");

  const filteredImoveis = tipo
    ? imoveis.filter((imovel) => imovel.tipo === tipo)
    : [];

  return (
    <>
      {filteredImoveis.length > 0 ? (
        <ul>
          {filteredImoveis.map((imovel, index) => (
            <li key={index} className="bg-neutral-200 m-2 text-black p-2 w-96">
              <div>
                <Link href={imovel.path}>
                  <p>{imovel.title}</p>
                  <p>{imovel.price}</p>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : (
        <p>Nenhum resultado encontrado.</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```